# Running armv7 android binaries on a github workflow

Tags: android, arm, github-actions

Basically I was trying to get my github project to build and run entirely in one of github's hosted runners (e.g. ubuntu-latest). The hard part is the latter which so far seems impossible to me. My project is entirely written in c++ and I build armv7 native binaries of it.

I found this github action: https://github.com/ReactiveCircus/android-emulator-runner
Which I tried using to run my tests. However even though it claims to support aarch64/armv7 images all my attempts of getting it up and running failed. The repository has no aarch64 tests of the emulator (I wonder why) and those that were added in one of the PRs I found failed.

The output I get from trying to use the action is:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A)
  INFO    | Found systemPath /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/system-images/android-24/default/arm[64](https://github.com/AngelDev06/AlterHook/actions/runs/7774797878/job/21200016640#step:8:67)-v8a/
  WARNING | encryption is off
  WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
  ERROR   | Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
  I0204 14:42:16.9[66](https://github.com/AngelDev06/AlterHook/actions/runs/7774797878/job/21200016640#step:8:69)798    2911 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
  I0204 14:42:16.977539    2911 FrameBuffer.cpp:486] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (Google Inc.)
  I0204 14:42:16.977558    2911 FrameBuffer.cpp:487] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader)
  I0204 14:42:16.9775[69](https://github.com/AngelDev06/AlterHook/actions/runs/7774797878/job/21200016640#step:8:72)    2911 FrameBuffer.cpp:488] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1)
  I0204 14:42:16.977576    2911 FrameBuffer.cpp:489] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 
  I0204 14:42:16.977584    2911 FrameBuffer.cpp:490] Graphics Device Extensions N/A
  WARNING: cannnot unmap ptr 0x7fb1f7bf5000 as it is in the protected range from 0x7fb1f7bf5000 to 0x7fb237df5000
  WARNING: cannnot unmap ptr 0x7fb237c01000 as it is in the protected range from 0x7fb1f7bf5000 to 0x7fb237df5000
  WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
  INFO    | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 2911
  INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
  INFO    | Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
  library_mode swiftshader_indirect gpu mode swiftshader_indirect
  INFO    | Using security allow list from: /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/emulator/lib/emulator_access.json
  WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
  INFO    | The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: /run/user/1001/avd/running/2911/jwks/93f8c2dd-0b0b-46a5-9cab-2c42bc8[71](https://github.com/AngelDev06/AlterHook/actions/runs/7774797878/job/21200016640#step:8:74)f5f/active.jwk
  INFO    | Scanning /run/user/1001/avd/running/2911/jwks/93f8c2dd-0b0b-46a5-9cab-2c42bc871f5f for jwk keys.
  INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
  INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1001/avd/running/pid_2911.ini
  [2915:2915:20240204,144217.01[84](https://github.com/AngelDev06/AlterHook/actions/runs/7774797878/job/21200016640#step:8:87)43:ERROR file_io_posix.cc:144] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
  [2915:2915:20240204,144217.0184[88](https://github.com/AngelDev06/AlterHook/actions/runs/7774797878/job/21200016640#step:8:91):ERROR file_io_posix.cc:144] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
  /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed
  * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
  * daemon started successfully
  adb: no devices/emulators found
  The process '/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb' failed with exit code 1
  /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed
  ^ keeps repeating the above till timeout...
```

And I initialized it with:

```
uses: ReactiveCircus/android-emulator-runner@v2.30.1
with:
  arch: arm64-v8a
  api-level: 24
  script: ./scripts/android-run-tests.sh ${{ steps.strings.outputs.cmake-preset }}
```

So my question is, is it possible to actually run my c++ native binaries somehow in a github workflow? I would prefer to automate the process of testing if possible and have it done automatically on github side.

Comment: Possibly related: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/run-arm-apps-on-android-emulator.html as your emulator images appears to API 24 or Android 7.0

Comment: @MorrisonChang yeah I tried using the arm emulation on an x86 emulator however it seems to work only for shared libraries packed within the apk. If for example I try to run a googletest executable using `adb shell` it's not gonna work and that's what I need in my case (since it's a pure native project)